# How would I record to a wave file using NAudio with more than 2 channels?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naudio

I have been trying to record to a single wave file with more than 2 channels with NAudio and I keep getting an InvalidParameter calling waveInOpen. I figured that this has to do with the fact that im trying to record with more than 2 channels.

The error occurs when the WaveIn.StartRecording() is called when the channel count is more than 2. It works when the channels are mono and stereo.

Is there a way to call the waveInOpen function with parameters that are outside the range? Is there a way to edit the waveInOpen function to accept more than 2 channels?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to record from that has more than two channels?  Can you record mono or stereo then upmix to a higher channel count?

Comment: i am going to be recording with multiple different devices into one wav file. to be seperated later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite often the soundcard drivers for your soundcard will not allow recording more than two channels. You could see if `WasapiCapture` can do it. Often the only sure way to get at all the channels is if your soundcard has an ASIO driver, and then you can use `AsioOut`

Comment: I used WasapiCapture to handle the multi-channel recording but i am still getting an error. Now it is an unsupported wave format. I am using an usb audio interface so that is not the issue. Its like NAudio wont accept any wave format that is over 2 channels. even when i load up a combobox with the available input devices, it is splitting my audio interface up into two channel segments like Analog (1+2), Analog (3 +4). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: NAudio is simply passing your requests on to the Windows APIs. Ultimately it is how your soundcard driver chooses to present itself to Windows. You might be able to persuade WASAPI to open multichannel output by creating a WaveFormatExtensible format with the correct parameters.

Comment: So i have tried the WASAPI with WaveFormatExtensible and as soon as i call startRecording() it crashed the app with this code "exited with code -1073740791". and if i just try it with a normal WaveFormat and WasapiCapture i get this error:
Unsupported Wave Format
at NAudio.CoreAudioApi.WasapiCapture.InitializeCaptureDevice():line 74
at NAudio.CoreAudioApi.WasapiCapture.StartRecording():line 95

at this point, im out of ideas on how to make NAudio record just 3 different mono channels

Comment: Is there a way to add waveFormats to NAudio so that it would be supported? and im sure its not the audio interface im using (scarlett 18i20)

Comment: With WaveFormatExtensible did you set it up as floating point? Also, you would need to open in exclusive mode to access more than 2 channels, *if* the focusrite driver allows this. But why not use ASIO? That will let you record all the channels. Pro audio interface manufacturers pretty much assume everyone uses ASIO on Windows these days.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it working with ASIO and it records how ever many channels the audio interface can handle!